# Logging with express-winston: wrong order of logs

Tags: express, winston

I'm using code like this:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const winston = require('winston');
const expressWinston = require('express-winston');

app.use(expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ],
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.printf(info => `Date from winston: ${Date.now()} ${info.message}`),
  ),
  expressFormat: true,
}));

app.get('/check', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Date from route: ${Date.now()}`);
    res.end('OK');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening...'));
```

and when I try to call `/check` route, I get this in the console:

```
Date from route: 1588531901238
Date from winston: 1588531901247 GET /check 200 2ms
```

As you can see, time from middleware is later than time from route handler.

Why? How can I fix it? I need to get right order of passing middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

This feature doesn't exist in express-winston yet according to this [issue](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/issues/118).

A workaround could be that you add a middleware to express before your routes to intercept all request and then log the information you need through your custom logger or you create a [custom transport in winston for that](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#adding-custom-transports). A simple example is just

```js
function logRequest(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request', req.path, Date.now());

  next();
}

app.use(logRequest);
// routes...
```

## Previous answer

**Question 1:**

> As you can see, time from middleware is later than time from route
>   handler. Why?

**Answer:**

This because the console transport `new winston.transports.Console()` logs your HTTP reqest to the console and not your `console.log(<some-text>)`. This is from the documentation of [express-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston#request-logging)

> Use expressWinston.logger(options) to create a middleware to log your
>   HTTP requests

To demonstrate this, lets take your code and see the result:

```js
// Your above code here...

app.get('/check', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Date from route: ${Date.now()}`);
    let i = 1;

    const handle = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('i:', i);
      i++;
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('i before response:', i);
      clearInterval(handle);
      res.end('OK');
    }, 3000);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening...'));
```

**Result**

```
Listening...
Date from route: 1588616514869
i: 1
i: 2
i before response: 3
Date from winston: 1588616517889 GET /check 200 3005ms
```

From the result we see that you only get the custom message `Date from winston: 1588616065807` from winston after you we call `res.end('OK')` instead of when we call `console.log('Date from route: ${Date.now()}');`.

**Question 2:**

> How can I fix it?

**Answer:**

Rather than using the default `console.log` you create your own logger where you format the message and then stdout. Something like this:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const winston = require('winston');

const { combine, timestamp, printf } = winston.format;
const myFormat = printf(({ message, timestamp }) => {
  const customMessage = `Date from winston: ${timestamp}`;
  return `${customMessage}\n${message}`;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ],
  format: combine(timestamp(), myFormat)
});

app.get('/check', (req, res) => {
  logger.info(`Date from route: ${Date.now()}`);
  let i = 1;

  const handle = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('i:', i);
    i++;
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('i before response:', i);
    clearInterval(handle);
    res.end('OK');
  }, 3000);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening...'));
```

**Result**

```
Listening...
Date from winston: 2020-05-04T18:26:26.508Z
Date from route: 1588616786506
i: 1
i: 2
i before response: 3
```

In this case you see the formatted message displays when you call `logger.info` rather than when you call `res.end('OK')`.

**In summary use your custom logger to get the logs look the way you want.**

Comment: Thanks for your answers! But it's not a good solution. In case if I try to call logger.info twice or more times, every time I get a line with "Date from winston:...". Secondly, it's avoiding the use of express-winston - I don't believe that I can't set up this middleware as I need. But you provided me an interesting idea, how to solve this problem: I will try to create separated loggers. Unfortunately, without express-winston for now. Thanks again!